# Count number of occurences of specific words in Excel sheet using python & xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I am writing a python script that finds excel sheets that are in the same directory as the script (I have about 10) and counts the number of occurrences of specific words in those files (like cloud, vmware, python etc.) then writes the total count of each word to a text file. I'm using python and xlrd to do this. Each excel file has a sheet called details which is where the info is. There are 2 columns and roughly 26 rows to each file.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):


if filename.find('xls') != -1:
    print filename        
    workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet=workbook.sheet_by_name("Details")
    values = []
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            values.append(unicode(sheet.cell(row,col).value))

            print values.count("cloud")
```

I am using a for loop to go through both columns and all rows of every file and then add all the values to a list. I then do the count using the list called values. I'll need a tally of some sort to total up the count of each word as everything is happening in a for loop which otherwise shows a count for each file. But unfortunately it doesn't work for some reason. I also need to set up a like a dictionary or something with all the words that I want to be counted but I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the reason as well? Any error msges, logs?

Comment: Oh ok. So it goes through every line of each file and comes up with a count of zero for each one on the console. I think the main problem is that I am looking for a word when each cell has at least a sentence in it. I think it's unable to see each individual word in each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for new questions you ask, it could be helpfull if you provide an example of the input data. and the expected output

I think you should change

```
values.append(unicode(sheet.cell(row,col).value))
```

to

```
if " " in sheet.cell(row,col):
    values.append(str(sheet.cell(row,col).value.split(" ")))
else:
    values.append(str(sheet.cell(row,col)))
```

In this case you have `values` containing all words (incluiding punctuation). You can remove punctuation and count the words with respectively [String](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and [Collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) modules.

```
from collections import Counter
import string
words = Counter(word.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for word in values)
```

`print words` should print all words in your excel files with a counter in front of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use the code words = Counter(word.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for word in values) it throws the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: try removing the unicode() step, I don't think you need that.

Comment: For print type(values) I get: <type 'list'> and for print values I get all text from the excel files being outputted. Here is an example of some of that text: [u'Hosting', u'complex', u'SAP', u'application', u'to', u'save', u'money'],

Comment: yea I edited my reply, you should really remove the unicode() step because then the type should be `<type 'str'>` and example text should be `['Hosting', 'complex', 'SAP', 'application', 'to', 'save', 'money']`

Comment: Ok when i get rid of the unicode, now it says AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: changed my answer, it does check wheter or not it contains a space. if it does you split, if it does not you don't split. also converts it to a string so you can .lower() it. I don't have your excel file so I cant test it before changing anything. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cells may or may not contain multiple words, so you have to `split` after substituting punctuation characters. Here, it's done with a translation map:

```
import xlrd
import os
from string import punctuation, translate
from collections import Counter

def count_words_trans():
    filename = u'test.xls'
    sheet_no = 1  # sheet is selected by index here
    path = '.'
    punctuation_map = dict((ord(c), u' ') for c in punctuation)

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
       if filename.endswith('.xls'):
          print filename
          workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
          sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(sheet_no)
          values = []
          for row in range(sheet.nrows):
              for col in range(sheet.ncols):
                  c = sheet.cell(row, col)
                  if c.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT:
                     cv = unicode(c.value)
                     wordlist = cv.translate(punctuation_map).split()
                     values.extend(wordlist)

          cnt = Counter(values)
          print sum(cnt.values()),' words counted,',len(cnt),' unique'
```

Text like 'action:run' is correctly split up into 2 words (different to just deleting punctuation). The translation method is unicode-safe. For efficiency, only cells containing text are read (no blanks, no dates, no numbers).
You get the list of word frequencies with:

```
for w in cnt.most_common():
    print '%s %s' % w
```